# Remove certain query string parameter UNLESS it was added by rewrite

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, bootstrapping

Using .htaccess I want to turn %{PATH_INFO} into a query string parameter for bootstrapping. But I want to prevent visitors from manually entering the bootstrap parameter.

**So this entered URL:** www.example.com/user/pictures?id=65

**Actually displays:** www.example.com?bootstrap=/user/pictures&id=65

*BUT if manually entered*

**This entered URL:** www.example.com?bootstrap=/user/pictures&id=65

**Removes it:** www.example.com?id=65

**Or displays an error:** 404:not found

*Best case scenario*

Manually entered bootstrap is ignored AND %{PATH_INFO} becomes a new parameter.

**So this:** www.example.com/user/pictures?id=65&bootstrap=somecrap

**Displays:** www.example.com?id=65&bootstrap=/user/pictures

There are two reasons to block a manually entered bootstrap parameter. 1) Security. We wouldn't want users hunting and pecking for files not intended for display. 2) Conflicts. We don't want to choose between a manually entered bootstrap and the correct %{PATH_INFO}.

Removing the bootstrap parameter is easy. Something like...

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?bootstrap=[^&]*(?:&(.*))?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [L,NE]
```

Adding the parameter is easy. (Mine is more complicated but this shows the idea.)

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}%{PATH_INFO} (.*?)(/.+)\2$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1?bootstrap=%2 [QSA,L]
```

If htaccess just ran through once, those two snippets would do the trick. But instead, htaccess restarts after every rewrite and my added bootstrap parameter gets removed again.

I know the quick-n-dirty fix would be to add [END] to the second rule, but that wont work here.

What I need is a way to remove ?"bootstrap=xxx" ONLY from the original request and NOT from rewritten request.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To recognize, if this is the original request or not, you can check certain [`REDIRECT_`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html#variables) variables

> `REDIRECT_` environment variables are created from the environment variables which existed prior to the redirect. They are renamed with a `REDIRECT_` prefix, i.e., `HTTP_USER_AGENT` becomes `REDIRECT_HTTP_USER_AGENT`.
>
> `REDIRECT_URL`, `REDIRECT_STATUS`, and `REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING` are guaranteed to be set, and the other headers will be set only if they existed prior to the error condition.

So in your case, you might check `REDIRECT_STATUS` or `REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING` to see, if this is an external or internal request.

Remove `bootstrap=` only, if this is an external request, i.e. `REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING` is empty

```
RewriteCond %{REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?bootstrap=[^&]*(?:&(.*))?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [L,NE]
```

The other way would be similar, though now check if the variables is *not* empty, e.g.

```
RewriteCond %{REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?bootstrap=[^&]*(?:&(.*))?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [L,NE]
```

You might also check for a specific value, if this is appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this is to set an environment variable on a successful rewrite, which you can do with the `E` flag. So something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^example$ ?param=example [E=rewritten:1]
```

You can then check for it in a condition:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:rewritten} !=1
```

Or:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:rewritten} =1
```

However, when using this in `.htaccess` you have to be careful, because if the pass through the `.htaccess` file completes and an internal redirect is generated, any environment variables generated will get `REDIRECT_` prepended to them. So for subsequent passes through, you also need to check for that in most cases, or just for that, if your rules are above where you add the environment variable:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_rewritten} !=1
```

Or:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_rewritten} =1
```

Reference:

- [Apache - The E/env flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_e)
- [Apache - Set Environment Variables Based On URL Parts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/advanced.html#setenvvars)